# Search result only for a specific value in a custom list view in android?

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I am using a custom list view and I want to search on a particular value.Right now I think my code search's for anything and everything matching the text entered.I want to search only for the doc_no.
The following is my code.

```
   public void showJson(String json) {
        final Context billsctx = getActivity();
        ParseBills pb = new ParseBills(json);
        pb.parseJSON();

        bl = new BillsCustomList((Activity) billsctx, ParseBills.doc_no, ParseBills.date, ParseBills.cust_name, ParseBills.cust_number, ParseBills.item_count, ParseBills.total_wt,
                ParseBills.total,ParseBills.balance, ParseBills.bill_type);


        all_listView.setAdapter(bl);




        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


                    bl.getFilter().filter(s);

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                if (s.length()==0)
                {
                    refreshFragment();
                }

            }
        });
```

}

This is my adapter code.

```
public class BillsCustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    private String[] doc_no;
    private String[]date;
    private String[] cust_name;
    private String[] cust_number;
    private String[] item_count;
    private String[]total_wt;
    private String[]total;
    private String[]balance;
    private String[]bill_type;

    private Activity context;

    public BillsCustomList(Activity context, String[] doc_no, String[] date, String[] cust_name,String[] cust_number,String[] item_count,String[] total_wt,String[] total,String[] balance,String[] bill_type)
    {
        super(context, R.layout.bills_list_view, doc_no);
        this.context =context;
        this.doc_no=doc_no;
        this.date = date;
        this.cust_name = cust_name;
        this.cust_number = cust_number;
        this.item_count= item_count;
        this.total_wt = total_wt;
        this.total = total;
        this.balance = balance;
        this.bill_type = bill_type;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bills_list_view, null, true);
        TextView textViewDocno = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewInvNo);
        TextView textViewDt = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewDt);
        TextView textViewName = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        TextView textViewNumber = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewNumber);
        TextView textViewCount = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewCount);
        TextView textViewTotwt = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewTotwt);
        TextView textViewTot = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewTot);
        TextView textViewBal = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewBalanace);
        TextView textViewBt = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewBt);

        textViewDocno.setText(doc_no[position]);
        textViewDt.setText(date[position]);
        textViewName.setText(cust_name[position]);
        textViewNumber.setText(cust_number[position]);
        textViewCount.setText(item_count[position]);
        textViewTotwt.setText(total_wt[position]);
        textViewTot.setText(total[position]);
        textViewBal.setText(balance[position]);
        textViewBt.setText(bill_type[position]);

        return listViewItem;
    }
}
```

Any suggestion or help is appreciated.Thank You.

Comment: what does refreshFragment() do?

Comment: @user3295583 refreshFragment() refresh's the list view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Implement Custom Filter like this:

```
 @Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter=new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
           FilterResults results=new FilterResults();
            if(constraint!=null)
            {
              places=getPredictions(constraint.toString());
                if(places!=null)
                {
                    results.values=places;
                    results.count=places.size();
                }
            }
            return results;
        }
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                // The API returned at least one result, update the data.
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                // The API did not return any results, invalidate the data set.
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };
    return filter;
}
```

This example is from:- http://coderzpassion.com/android-working-google-places-api/    but u can try and modify it according to requirement.  Thanks. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code.

```
 ArrayList<String> type_name_copy = new ArrayList<String>();

 inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
           ArrayList<String> type_name_filter = new ArrayList<String>();

            String text = theWatchedText.toString();

            for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {

                if ((ParseBills.doc_no[i].toLowerCase()).contains(text
                        .toLowerCase())) {
                    type_name_filter.add(ParseBills.doc_no[i]);

                }
            }

            type_name_copy = type_name_filter;//use this to update list


        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable theWatchedText) {

        }
    });
```